# angular reactive form checkboxes

Tags: angular

I'm building a page, reactive form, which will show a list of checkboxes, in the list some of the items must be checked based on the data received.

The data is coming in 2 different arrays, one which contains all the checkboxes (RULE_LOOKUP_ID, DESCRIPTION) and another which is just the list of ids which were previously checked ("RULE_IDS": [1, 3]).

I'm having some problems getting it to display, assuming i'm not setting up the form properly.

I'm building a formgroup as:

```
  this.ruleAssignmentFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  RULE_LOOKUP_ID: this.detail.RULE_LOOKUP_ID,
  TITLE: new FormControl(this.detail.TITLE),
  checkedRules: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  allRules: []
});
```

Checked rules will the ids of the ones which are checked and allRules will contain everything.

populating it with:

```
        let control = <FormArray>this.ruleAssignmentFormGroup.controls.checkedRules;
    foundItem.RULE_IDS.forEach(x => {
      control.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        RuleLookupChkBox: new FormControl(x),
      }));
    });
```

my form looks like:

```
  <form [formGroup]="ruleAssignmentFormGroup" autocomplete="false" novalidate class="form-horizontal">
<div class="card-body form-styles">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ruleAssignmentFormGroup.controls['TITLE'].value}}</label>
      </div>
      <div formArrayName="checkedRules">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div *ngFor="let item of ruleAssignmentFormGroup.get('allRules'); let i=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
              <input type="checkbox" formControlName="RuleLookupChkBox" [value]="item.RuleLookupId">{{item.DESCRIPTION}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the form throws errors when it comes up:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

and

> Cannot find control with path: 'checkedRules -> 1'
>
> Cannot find control with path: 'checkedRules -> 1 -> RuleLookupChkBox'

the data looks to be populated properly in the ruleAssignmentFormGroup.  is there another way to get this to work?

Comment: Probably you meant `ruleAssignmentFormGroup.get('allRules').controls` in ngFor

Answer (score 0):

- You need to initiate allRules as a FormArray: `this.formBuilder.array([])`
- I would put an *ngIf on the form tag to ensure it doesn't try to render before the data coming back

  - Suggestion: `*ngIf="foundItem && foundItem.RULE_IDS" or you can set a boolean at the end of the API call and cite that property in *ngIf
- `ruleAssignmentFormGroup.get('allRules')` will return an instance of AbstractControl. You need to *ngFor on it's controls, which is an array.

  - Suggestion: `*ngFor="let item of ruleAssignmentFormGroup.controls.allRules.controls"`